How to inversely wire a switch that driven by a light sensor
I’m looking for a light sensor that operates inversely: turning off my garden fountain pump when it gets dark and turning it on when it gets light. I guess you could rewire a commonly sold light sensor switch, but I’m not a qualified electrician

"Dawn to dusk'".

Ah, it's been running on a timer for 3 years. It can go a bit longer.  Just found the idea of "dawn to dusk" sensor interesting.

@RMDman, apologies. I mistook you for the OP at one point there.

The simplest solutions would be either using a relay to invert the behavior of a standard switch, or using smart home technology and simply programming the on and off appropriately.

You have an answer in a comment, that will hopefully become an answer. But ... I am not fond of light-sensing switches because they are very sensitive to location.  They usually come with wires that are not long enough to get from wherever you want to put the controller to a place out in the open.  The linked one in particular has its socket and sensor in the same hunk of plastic.  So the plug, socket, and computer all need to be out in the open.  It might work!  I just don't like them.
I recommend a timer instead.  Some examples:

Most simple digital timer switches allow you to specify Dawn or Dusk as the time for either On or Off events.  They are not "Connected", you have to specify your location (a crude single-digit latitude) and DST convention and they more or less get it right.
Most Smart switches and plugs can be programmed for Dawn and Dusk events through their app.  Some require a matching hub, some can do this stuff on their own.  When I put uplights on my bushes I bought a cheap transformer with no timer, no Internet, no nuthin, and a separate $15 smart plug that does dusk to dawn (but could do the opposite, or anything you want) and also allows me to turn them on and off from my phone.


Photocell sensors are not easily reversible and it is not practical to do so.
The easiest way to get your fountain to turn on and off is with a timer.
If the power source originates outside there are indoor/ outdoor rated timers that can be added to the wiring. 120 and 240v versions are available.
If you can source the power indoors, say in a garage or basement, you can use a programable smart timer.
You may need to reprogram or reset time twice a year for time change and occasionally otherwise. However timers are the common and easiest solution to your problem. Smart timers can often be controlled with your phone.
